# Can't install anything. Error "unmet dependencies"

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I can't install anything on my Ubuntu. It gives me the following error.
I tried all the things I found on different websites but it still doesn't work.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libpcap0.8-dev: Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
sqlite3: Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but 6.3-4ubuntu2 is installed
         Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2 is installed
```

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release? Did you run `apt-get update` (or equivalent) recently? Did it show any warning or error messages? What's the output of `apt-cache policy libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-0`?

Answer (score 0):

Check for correct repos for your version of Ubuntu in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to “[c]heck for correct repos for your version”. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)